# Hide images on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simpler way to code this so that we don't have to keep inserting each consecutive number? Maybe just the first and last.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("#001,#002,#003,#004,#005,#006,#007,#008,#009,#010,#011,#012,#013,#014,#015,#016,#017,#018,#019,#020,#021,#022,#023,#024,#025,#026,#027,#028,#029,").css("display", "none");});  
</script>
```

Comment: What?? whats that with the question description ?

Comment: Can't you just put some common class on the elements with those ids?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to go would be is to assign a class to all these elements

Then

```
$('.myClass').css('display', 'none')
```

would get the work done.

Otherwise you would need to use a Regex to capture them..

A simple regex can do

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return /[0-9]+/.test(this.id);
}).addClass('a')
```

*Assuming all of these are span elements.*

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MK2JN/)**

Comment: That regex will match all IDs that contain a digit. Perhaps you want something more specific: `/^0[0-2][0-9]$/`

Comment: @JanDvorak.. There ya go.. Just learning regexs.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you must do it this way you can use a jQuery filter on a group of selectors.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return this.id.match(/^0[0-2][0-9]$/);
}).css('display', 'none');
```

But regexes are expensive and I would recommend you use classes instead.

Comment: Your regex will match all IDs that contain a digit. Perhaps you want something more specific: `/^0[0-2][0-9]$/`

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks. Clearly regexes are not my speciality :)

Answer (score 0):

you could essentially hide all images by doing the following

```
$('img').hide();
```

however this will hide all images on the page so you can put all these images in a container, like so:

```
<div id='MyImgContainer'>
//Add images here
</div>
```

the js

```
$('#MyImgContainer').hide();
```